# Spring jsp submit form with onetomany relation

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have two Entity: **StoryType** and **Stories**.
StoryType may have many stories.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stories")
public class Story {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "crdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date crDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "story_type_id")
    private StoryType storyType;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="story_types")
public class StoryType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="storyType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Story> stories;
}
```

I have form on jsp page where I'm adding story and I should to select type of story. But when i see what values are submitted, there are only name and description, storyType - null. How can i send also object from select or even just type id?

```
<form role="form" action="/admin/add-story" method="post" commandName="story">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" autofocus="true" placeholder="Enter name" value="${story.name}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <c:forEach items="${types}" var="type">
                <option name="storyType" value="${type}">${type.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Desscription</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" autofocus="true" value="${story.description}">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

in the client, you could store only `id` of `StoryType`

```
<select class="form-control">
        <c:forEach items="${types}" var="type">
            <option name="storyType" value="${type.id}">${type.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

when post data to server , client will post the `type.id` to server. We create a Spring Converter to get a `StoryType` object from database.

```
public class StoryTypeConverter implements Converter<String, StoryType >{

@Autowired
private StoryTypeService storyTypeService;

public StoryType convert(String id) {
    return storyTypeService.findById(Long.valueOf(id));
   }
}
```

Register the convertionService

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="com.somepackage.StoryTypeConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After that, the object in controller will contain StoryType. 
I whether is there another way to solve this problem.
Think it could help

Comment: unfortunately when i run my application in debug mode i see that converter is not called

Comment: I am not sure, my pr0ject use spring converter and anything work ok